# convert a map containing list of values to another map containing average of all the values in the list

Tags: java

I am converting a map containing keys and corresponding list of values to Map<String, Double> where the value is average score. Is there a concise way to do this?

```
        Map<String, List<Float>> scoresMap = Map.of(
                "Prod1", List.of(2f, 2f, 2f, 2f),
                "Prod2", List.of(4f, 4f, 4f, 4f),
                "Prod3", List.of(6f, 6f, 6f, 6f),
                "Prod4", List.of(8f, 8f, 8f, 8f));


        Map<String, Double> averageScores = new HashMap<>();

        scoresMap.forEach( (key, value) -> {
            averageScores.put(key, value.stream().mapToDouble(d -> d).average().getAsDouble());
                }
        );
```

Comment: How much more concise could this be?

Comment: I am creating a new map variable `averageScores` in this implementation. I was wondering if this could be collected into a map using `collect` operation instead of explicitly putting the values into a new map.

Comment: If it's even possible, I strongly feel that the resulting code would be even less _readsble_, and likely not more "concise" (whatever definition of that word you mean). If you really want to reduce this to a single line, my opinion would be to encapsulate it in a method with a good, descriptive name as a better move towards readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using the [`toMap` collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-):

```
final Map<String, List<Float>> scoresMap = Map.of(
        "Prod1", List.of(2f, 2f, 2f, 2f),
        "Prod2", List.of(4f, 4f, 4f, 4f),
        "Prod3", List.of(6f, 6f, 6f, 6f),
        "Prod4", List.of(8f, 8f, 8f, 8f));

final Map<String, Double> averageScores = scoresMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                entry -> entry.getValue()
                        .stream()
                        .mapToDouble(d -> d)
                        .average()
                        .getAsDouble()));
```

To keep the code readable, I'd suggest extracting the averaging operation into a separate method:

```
final double average(final Collection<Float> floats) {
    return floats.stream()
            .mapToDouble(d -> d)
            .average()
            .getAsDouble();
}

final Map<String, Double> averageScores = scoresMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                entry -> average(entry.getValue())));
```

or perhaps even:

```
final Function<Map.Entry<?, List<Float>>, Double> averaging
        = entry -> average(entry.getValue());
final Map<String, Double> averageScores = scoresMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, averaging));
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it is certainly possible to convert the map into a stream and then collect the entries back into a map, I'm not entirely convinced that this approach makes the most sense.

```
    var map = scoresMap.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    e -> e.getValue().stream().collect(
                            Collectors.averagingDouble(Float::doubleValue)
                    )
            ));
```

Perhaps if there is further processing to do in the stream it makes sense to do this but it risks obfuscating the purpose of the code in my opinion.